# Is there a way to add native rules to Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I would like a set of rules from `my_package.bzl` to be accessible to all `BUILD` files of a workspace without having to `load` `my_package.bzl` in the `BUILD` files. Basically I want the rules in the package to look like native rules. How can I achieve this?

I was thinking maybe there's a line I could add to one of the `.bazelrc`s or to the `WORKSPACE` file of the the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding a `prelude_bazel` file at `//tools/build_rules:prelude_bazel` (this must be a package, so `tools/build_rules` must contain a `BUILD` file).
This will be loaded and prepended to all `BUILD` files loaded by Bazel.

However, there are a few things to consider before going this route. It's currently undocumented, and while doing some searching to find any info on this feature, it's unclear if it will remain a part of Bazel.

It may also have performance / scaling problems. If the `prelude` were to change (or any of its dependencies), every BUILD file would have to be reloaded, and this may take some time depending on the size of the build graph.

Comment: Thanks man! Worked perfectly. Do you happen to have any sources about Bazel besides the google discuss group, the official docs or issues on Github? I'm wondering where you found that.

Comment: I _think_ I first came across `prelude_bazel` in the (now deprecated) [build file generator for Java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/BUILD_file_generator/blob/master/tools/build_rules/prelude_bazel)
The source for the prelude adding is [here](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/master:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/BazelRuleClassProvider.java;l=227)