# Is it possible to define custom bazel macro or rule and load it in workspace for all packages?

Tags: global-variables, global, bazel

I wrote a custom [bazel](https://bazel.build) macro, in order to shorten code in my BUILD files. I want it to be available in *all* BUILD files, and I don't want to call [load statement](https://bazel.build/concepts/build-files#load) each time.

So I want to use it just like I use symbols from [native](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/native) module.

Is it possible to do such thing without changing bazel sources?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding a prelude_bazel file at //tools/build_rules:prelude_bazel (this must be a package, so tools/build_rules must contain a BUILD file). This will be loaded and prepended to all BUILD files loaded by Bazel.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168219/is-there-a-way-to-add-native-rules-to-bazel)

Comment: Thank you! I would never find the original question, because in fact the goal is not to make the native rule, but to make the global one. So I'll keep this question unless moderators decide the opposite.